# How to add text and buttons to the first image on my slider

Tags: html, css, text, slider

Here is the html for my image slider. Trying to add buttons and text to the first image but something keeps overriding.

```
**<div id="captioned-gallery">
    <figure class="slider">
      <figure> 
        <img src="images/multipurpose.jpg"> 
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="images/sanitizer.jpg" alt>  
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="images/glycerine.jpg" alt>       
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="images/multipurpose.jpg" alt> 
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="images/sanitizer.jpg" alt> 
      </figure>
   </figure>
 </div>**
```

// Here is the text and buttons I would like to use on the first image.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-8" alt="Clean Haven Products, Clean Haven Multipurpose Soap, Affordable Soap manufacturers in Nairobi">

<div class="hero-wrapper text-center mb-4">
  <h1 class="hero-title text-white mb-4">Creating Products and Building Solutions is what
 <span class="text-primary">we do.</span>
  </h1>
    <p class="text-white-50">We would love to tell you more about us or get in touch.</p>

        <div class="mt-4">
          <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mr-2" alt="clean haven soap">Contact Us</a>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-success mt-2 mr-2">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//Css for my image slider below as requested by Evik:-

```
  div#captioned-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
 
  figure.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  }
  figure.slider figure { 
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
  }

  figure.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

//End of css for image slider

Comment: Can you share your css please.

Comment: Hi, there is the css, thanks @EvikGhazarian

Comment: @EvikGhazarian hey, thanks, this has worked like a charm. Just wondering how I can make the text and buttons responsive in both the desktop and mobile versions. Thanks

Comment: You can use @media queries in your css and implement different styles based on your screen size. I've updated the answer with some examples of media queries. Verify the answer if it helped thanks.

Comment: Ahh great, the media queries work as well. Really appreciate Evik. @EvikGhazarian

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I created for you. I hope this is what you want.

Added a div with class content and position absolute. You can position is however you want. The way I positioned is 25% from the top and horizontally middle.

**UPDATE:** Updated with media queries. Here I only changed the color in different screen sizes. But you can change anything you want. position, size, etc with media queries.

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  
  div#captioned-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
 
  figure.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  }
  figure.slider figure { 
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
  }

  figure.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.content {
color: green;
background-color: cyan;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
.content {
color: red;
background-color: lightgreen;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.content {
color: blue;
background-color: yellow;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery">
    <figure class="slider">
      <figure> 
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        <div class="content">
        Hello
        </div>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt>  
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt>       
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt> 
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt> 
      </figure>
   </figure>
 </div>
```